# Make char uppercase within String

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, char

I want to make the vowels of a String uppercase. Here's the method for it:

```
public static String LetterChanges(String str) {

        char[] strChar = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i =0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'){
                Character.toUpperCase(ch);
                str.replace(strChar[i], ch);
            }
        }
     return str;
}
```

That "if" statement will pick up a vowel, but I can't figure out how to make it uppercase. IntelliJ says the results of .toUpperCase and .replace are both ignored. Could somebody please explain why those methods are ignored, and also perhaps point me in the right direction with this code?

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ says that the results of those operations are ignored because strings and characters are immutable in Java. The result of any operation performed on them needs to be assigned back to the variable, e.g.:

```
ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
str = str.replace(strChar[i], ch);
```

As for the actual program, it's sufficient to loop over an array of vowels, and use `String.replace(char old, char new)` for every vowel. The operation will replace all occurrences of that vowel in the string:

```
String string = "Whatever string";
char[] vowels = new char[]{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

for (char vowel : vowels) {
    string = string.replace(vowel, Character.toUpperCase(vowel));
}

System.out.println(string); // WhAtEvEr strIng
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that is all that was needed. I get it now, Strings and chars are basically going to need special treatment because of their immutability. It actually makes a lot more sense now. Thank you, Robby!!

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't update the original string that is taken as input. The **replace** method modifies your string and returns a string which you aren't assigning back to the input. Also the **Character.toUppercase()**; method returns the character back which you have to replace.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "This is my input string";
    char[] strChar = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
            str = str.replace(strChar[i], Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

A simpler way to do the above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "This is my input string";
        System.out.println(input.replace("a", "A").replace("e", "E").replace("i", "I").replace("o", "O").replace("u", "U"));
}
```